# How to disable horizontal scrolling when picture width exceeds viewport width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, viewport

This is my HTML with styles:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
  html {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 70vh;
    background-color: deeppink;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
 @media (orientation:landscape){
       body{
          height:70vw;
          width:70vw;
       }
   }
</style>

<body></body>

</html>
```

I wanted a circle that was slightly cut on both left & right sides(mobile) and up & down (for desktop) so i thought this was the best way but what I observe is that the page also ends up with extra width on mobile and extra height on desktop, I don't want this to happen.

Is there any way deal with this so the circles remain cut and removing the scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Use `heigth: 100%` and `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` on your `html` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
  html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 70vh;
    background-color: deeppink;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
 @media (orientation:landscape){
       body{
          height:70vw;
          width:70vw;
       }
   }
</style>

<body></body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I test the snippet on responsive mode of chrome, It does not scroll! What are the sizes of your device? and also is it your full example? @Enceladus

Comment: Android device, 720x1440, i would have posted pictures but i dont have enough rep

Comment: I add the picture of your width and height. @Enceladus